# IPsec - Clients cannot ping each other

Tags: client, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I'm having a hard time to finalize a first working configuration with IPsec.

I want to have a IPsec server that creates a network with its clients, and I want the clients to be able to communicate each other through the server. I'm using Strongswan on both server and clients, and I'll have a few clients with other IPsec implementations.

### Problem

So the server is reachable at 10.231.0.1 for every clients and the server can ping the clients. It works well. But the clients cannot reach each other.

Here is an output of tcpdump when I try to ping 10.231.0.2 from 10.231.0.3

```
# tcpdump -n host 10.231.0.3
[..]
21:28:49.099653 ARP, Request who-has 10.231.0.2 tell 10.231.0.3, length 28
21:28:50.123649 ARP, Request who-has 10.231.0.2 tell 10.231.0.3, length 28
```

I thought of farp plugin, mentionned here : https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling but the ARP request is not making its way to the server, it stays local.

### Information

**Server ipsec.conf**

```
config setup
  charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
  uniqueids=no

conn ikev2-vpn
  auto=add
  compress=no
  type=tunnel
  keyexchange=ikev2
  fragmentation=yes
  forceencaps=yes
  dpdaction=clear
  dpddelay=300s
  esp=aes256-sha256-modp4096!
  ike=aes256-sha256-modp4096!
  rekey=no
  left=%any
  leftid=%any
  leftcert=server.crt
  leftsendcert=always
  leftsourceip=10.231.0.1
  leftauth=pubkey
  leftsubnet=10.231.0.0/16
  right=%any
  rightid=%any
  rightauth=pubkey
  rightsourceip=10.231.0.2-10.231.254.254
  rightsubnet=10.231.0.0/16
```

**Client ipsec.conf**

```
config setup
  charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
  uniqueids=no

conn ikev2-vpn
  auto=route
  compress=no
  type=tunnel
  keyexchange=ikev2
  fragmentation=yes
  forceencaps=yes
  dpdaction=clear
  dpddelay=60s
  esp=aes256-sha256-modp4096!
  ike=aes256-sha256-modp4096!
  rekey=no
  right=server.url
  rightid=%any
  rightauth=pubkey
  rightsubnet=10.231.0.1/32
  left=%defaultroute
  leftid=%any
  leftauth=pubkey
  leftcert=client.crt
  leftsendcert=always
  leftsourceip=10.231.0.3
  leftsubnet=10.231.0.3/32
```

*There should be nothing special or relevant in Strongswan's & charon's configuration file, but I can provide them if you think that could be usefull.*

I've taken a few shortcuts in the configuration : I'm using VirtualIP but I'm not using a DHCP plugin or anything to distribute the IP. I'm setting the IP address manually on the clients like so :

```
ip address add 10.231.0.3/16 dev eth0
```

And here is a routing table on the client's side (automatically set like that by adding the IP and by Strongswann for the table 220) :

```
# ip route list | grep 231
10.231.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.231.0.3

# ip route list table 220
10.231.0.1 via 192.168.88.1 dev eth0 proto static src 10.231.0.3
```

I've also played with iptables and this rule

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -m policy --pol ipsec --dir out -j ACCEPT
```

On both client and server, because I understood that could be a problem if I have MASQUERADE rules already set, but that did not changed anything.

I've also set those kernel parameters through sysctl on both client and server side :

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.default.accept_redirects=0
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.default.send_redirects=0
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_redirects=0
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects=0
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp=1
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp=1
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

### Lead 1

This could be related to my subnets declared in /32 in my client's configurations. At first I declared the subnet in /16 but I could not connect two clients with this configuration. The second client was taking the whole traffic for itself. So I understood I should limit the traffic selectors and this is how I did it but maybe I'm wrong.

### Lead 2

This could be related to my way of assigning IP manually, and the mess it can introduce in the routing table. When I play with the routing table manually assigning gateway (like the public IP of the client as a gateway) then the ARP in TCPdump disappear and I see the ICMP request. But absolutely nothing on the server.

Any thoughts on what I've done wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have kernel parameter `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` set on server side?

Comment: Yes sorry this is among the parameters that have been set, I forgot to put this one in the description

Comment: I'm not sure it's something from the server side. Because when I'm trying to reach another client from a client, I do not see anything coming on the server (I tried several tcpdump filters). This looks like a routing problem on the client or something like that, but I cannot figure it out.